# What is the meaning of "stat" in the SFTP error message "Couldn't stat remote file"

Tags: sftp

I've seen this when using SFTP; for example when I try to remove a file that isn't on the remote server:

```
sftp> RM coa.dat.gz
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
Removing coa.dat.gz
Couldn't delete file: No such file or directory
```

Since "stat" isn't an English verb, this is a bit confusing.

It is clear that this has something to do with the UNIX/Linux command [`stat`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/stat.htm) or the C function `stat()`, but I welcome a more complete description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sftp` server is indeed trying to `stat()` the file before removing it.  The file it tried to stat didn't exist therefore it couldn't `stat` the (remote) file and gave you the `strerror_r()` of the error number that stat received "No such file or directory"

`$ man 2 stat` ... it's in section 2 because it's a system call, not a section 3 standard library call.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/unix-stat-command-how-to-identify-file-attributes/), "Stat command displays file or filesystem status..." Note that the error may be generated because of lack of / improper permissions. Be sure to check that you have the appropriate permissions on the file/directory.

Comment: The directory/file is on a remote system running an sftp server, so he may be unable to check the permissions there; but if it *were* a problem with permissions the text following `Couldn't stat remote file:` would say something else, instead of "No such file or directory"